# How can I make a 2D sprite move by adding the input from Vertical and Horizontal axis to transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, controls

So I was wondring if there's a way I can make a 2D character/sprite move by adding the 1 and -1 that the Horizontal and Vertical Axis is returning. The reason is I want my character to move with constant distance, so each press of walk button adds one to the transform so it's never gonna be a float or never gonna be having a decimal value.

```
public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

Void Update()
{
      float Horizontal_x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      float Vertical_y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
      
      rb2d.transform.x * Horizontal_x * Time.deltaTime;
      rb2d.transform.y * Horizontal_y * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: You could create a variable IntMove and add to it with the input and when it reaches 1 reset it to 0 and move the character by 1

Answer (score 0):

```
public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

Void Update()
{
      int Horizontal_x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      int Vertical_y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
      
      rb2d.transform.x += Horizontal_x * Time.deltatime;
      rb2d.transform.y += Horizontal_y * Time.deltatime;
}
```

your syntax was wrong. I replaced the `*` with `+=` which i assume would be what u intended to write. the `int` does just what u expect it too. if not , use this one :

```
public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

Void Update()
{
      float Horizontal_x = Mathf.round(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
      float Vertical_y = Mathf.round(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
      
      rb2d.transform.x * Horizontal_x * Time.deltaTime;
      rb2d.transform.y * Horizontal_y * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: Hello. So I did this but the code is still not making the sprite/character to move.
`
       Vector2 pos = rb2d.transform.position;

        float Horizontal_x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float Horizontal_y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        pos.x += Horizontal_x * Time.deltaTime;
        pos.y += Horizontal_y * Time.deltaTime;
`

Comment: (your code did not get formatted correctly).

you forgot to do `rb2d.transform.position = pos; ` and you didn't do the `round` nor made the variables an `int`. ( i wrote the examples. you can copy-paste them )